# Check if file is a valid jpg

Tags: java

I would like to check if the file I am reading in from a directory is a jpg but I do not want to simply check the extension. I am thinking an alternative is to read the header. I have done some research and I want to use

```
ImageIO.read
```

I have seen the example

```
String directory="/directory";     

BufferedImage img = null;
try {
   img = ImageIO.read(new File(directory));
} catch (IOException e) {
   //it is not a jpg file
}
```

I am not sure where to go from here, it takes in the entire directory... but I need each jpg file in the directory.  Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code or what additions need to be made?

Thank you!

Comment: Where to go from there depends on what you want to do :)

Comment: You may want to be a bit more specific as to what is going wrong. Is the code not compiling, not doing anything, etc? From looking at the code it seems that you just put in an alert or something where the comment is, which will warn you if it isn't a jpeg, and otherwise there will be no use of the catch block if it really is a jpeg.

Comment: Learn how to read bytes (binary, `byte []`, not `String`) from a file in Java, that's pretty 101 stuff... Then look at the bytes (jpg header).

Comment: @hyde Sorry I am new to java... do you mind providing an example

Comment: @Teddy13 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/ and there click "byte streams"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can read the first bytes stored in the buffered image. This will give you the exact file type

```
Example for GIF it will be
GIF87a or GIF89a 

For JPEG 
image files begin with FF D8 and end with FF D9
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)

Try this

```
  Boolean status = isJPEG(new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Chrysanthemum.jpg"));
System.out.println("Status: " + status);


private static Boolean isJPEG(File filename) throws Exception {
    DataInputStream ins = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));
    try {
        if (ins.readInt() == 0xffd8ffe0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;

        }
    } finally {
        ins.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: For JPEG, the file starts with a header containing segment offsets. The characters "JFIF" [actually appear at the start of the APP0 segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure).

Comment: I tried with some JPEG files but in some cases the integer read is 0xffd8ffe1 so I think it is better to check for just 2 bytes i.e. 0xFFD8

Answer (score 4):

You will need to get the readers used to read the format and check that there are no readers available for the given file...

```
String fileName = "Your image file to be read";
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File(fileName ));
Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("jpg");
boolean canRead = false;
while (readers.hasNext()) {
    try {        
        ImageReader reader = readers.next();
        reader.setInput(iis);
        reader.read(0);
        canRead = true;
        break;
    } catch (IOException exp) {
    }        
}
```

Now basically, if none of the readers can read the file, then it's not a Jpeg

**Caveat**

This will only work if there are readers available for the given file format.  It might still be a Jpeg, but no readers are available for the given format...

Answer (score 2):

Improving the answer given by @karthick you can do the following:

```java
private static Boolean isJPEG(File filename) throws IOException {
    try (DataInputStream ins = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)))) {
        return ins.readInt() == 0xffd8ffe0;
    }
}
```