# Detect if given file is image and is valid image of specific type in java

Tags: java, image, file-type

I have requirement to get from user input file which should be image only of specified type. E.g. only `JPEG`s. Other files must be rejected.

So I implemented naive basic check for file

```
fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg")
```

So if user uploaded file.png, this file was rejected. But then users realized, that if they simply rename file.png to file.jpg, the file will be uploaded.

Is there way to detect if supplied file is valid image of given type using only `JAVA SDK` without external jars? (note I'm still working with JDK6). Thanks.

Comment: I think this is what you want : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643228/test-if-file-is-an-image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539696/check-if-file-is-jpg

Comment: You might want to rethink your user experience here. Does it really matter if the image is a JPG or a PNG?

Comment: @Tim B Well, it is an requirement and I can only obey it. There are another processes, that rely on specified file format.

Comment: You can use ImageIO to transcode the PNG to JPG. If you really need to restrict them though then the answers below should cover it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be relatively easy to do some naive checking to separate a JPEG from a PNG. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure), JPEG files always start with `FF D8`. PNGs however seem to start with `89 50`, so one can easily distinguish between the two from just reading a byte or two from the file.

I would recommend looking up the file formats of the most important image types just to make sure there isn't some other mainstream one starting with `FF D8`. It seems unlikely however.

Edit: JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP and TIFF all seem to have magic values at the start of the files to tell them apart form other types.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Seems a good point to start with. I will try.

Answer (score 2):

Decode the file as jpeg and see if it throws an Exception or returns an image?

You can use JDK ImageIO to do this (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html). Start by obtaining ImageReader for jpeg, then let that reader attempt to read the image.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will use your suggestion as a "backup solution", because I think that using exceptions in this way is generally not the best approach. As I was told by a wise man, exception processing should be used only if there is no other way to prevent exception to ocurr, in other words, Exceptions should be used only when situation is exceptional.

Comment: However invalid user input is a valid exceptional situation.

Comment: @user3195535 You're taking the "exceptions for exceptional sitatuions" out of scope by taking it too literally. The decisive point is that an exception should be used to indicate that the operation to be performed can't be completed normally - the *context* that is *requesting* the operation is irrelevant for deciding if an exception is appropiate or not. If you think your logic through to the end, exceptions were only allowed to be thrown when the world ends.

Comment: @Durandal I agree with your comment. My comment was ment a bit different. Maybe little example will make my thoughts clear. Consider operations with File. I would preffer to use file.exists() test instead of processing FileNotFoundException because I can prevent this exception to raise by testing that existence.